# PHP 5.2: Filter array with multiple arguments performance

Tags: php, arrays, performance

I'm using this code to filter a multidimensional array:

```
$sourceArray = array(
                array('name'=>'banana', 'color'=>'green'),
                array('name'=>'banana', 'color'=>'black'),
                array('name'=>'banana', 'color'=>'yelow'),
          );
$arrayToCompare = array('type'=>'fruits','has_name'=>'banana', 'has_color'=>'yelow');

$filtered = array();

foreach($sourceArray as $item) {
   if($item['name'] !== $arrayToCompare['has_name']) continue;
   if($item['color'] !== $arrayToCompare['has_color']) continue;
   $filtered[] = $item;
}
```

But I think there might be an efficient/quicker solution.

In PHP 5.3 we can use anonymous functions (closures) inside the native [filter_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) but they are not supported in 5.2:

```
$filtered = array_filter(
                $masterItems,
                function ($arr) use ($arrayToCompare) { // PHP 5.3 is required here!!
                    return ($arr['name'] == $arrayToCompare['has_name']
                        AND $arr['color'] == $arrayToCompare['has_color']);
                }
            );
```

Are there any better approaches in term of speed?

Comment: array_filter try this

Comment: Any `callable` can be used -why not make a named function and use that?

Comment: I'm sure you're already painfully aware of it, but please note that php 5.2 is obsolete. *VERY* obsolete. It was declared end-of-life nearly half a decade ago, and hasn't had any security patches since then. If you're running it on a public web server, you are exposing yourself to a lot of risk. You'll also find that any third-party libraries/frameworks you're relying on will also be obsolete, as pretty much everyone dropped support for php 5.2 some time ago, so you'll be stuck on old versions, again probably with nasty security holes. I strongly recommend that you try to upgrade if possible.

Comment: Thanks @Simba but some of our clients... Unfortunately & dangerously still use it :(

Comment: @numediaweb: Yep, I feel your pain. So do some of ours. It's not easy to convince some people. Please do keep reminding them of the potential risks they're running though. And if you can, I also recommend charging extra to support such an obsolete system.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.2 accepts the name of a callback in the `array_filter` function.

```
function filter($arr)
{
    $arrayToCompare = array('type'=>'fruits','has_name'=>'banana', 'has_color'=>'yelow');

    return $arr['name'] == $arrayToCompare['has_name']
          && $arr['color'] == $arrayToCompare['has_color'];
}

$filtered = array_filter($masterItems, 'filter');
```

Comment: The use of global in PHP is not recommended.

Comment: @numediaweb I'm aware of that, I just used it as an example. Anyway, I edited the answer :)