# PHP array_filter multi callback

Tags: callback, array-filter

How can I set `multifilter` or `multicallback`?

I want filter data by `City` and `Confirm` together.

Input data:

```
$data1 = array(
            "L1" => array('Vanessa', 'Prague', 'OK'),
            "L2" => array('Alex', 'Paris', 'OK'),
            "L3" => array('Paul', 'Paris', 'OK'),
            "L4" => array('John', 'Madrid', 'OK'),
            "L5" => array('Jane', 'London', 'Waiting'),
            "L6" => array('David', 'Prague', 'OK'),
            "L7" => array('Martin', 'Prague', 'Waiting'),
            "L8" => array('Frank', 'Prague', 'OK'),
            "L9" => array('Joseph', 'Prague', 'Waiting'),
            );
```

Filter code:

```
$ByConfirm = 'OK'; 
$ByCity = 'Prague';
```

Below is my problem. I try use `&&`, but it works separately, I need cooperation of `$filterByConfirm` + `$filterByCity`

```
$new = array_filter($data1, $filterByConfirm && $filterByCity);

      $filterByConfirm =  $new = array_filter($data1, function ($var) use ($ByConfirm) {
            return ($var[2] == $ByConfirm); 
      });

      $filterByCity =  $new = array_filter($data1, function ($var) use ($ByCity) {
            return ($var[1] == $ByCity); 
      });
```

Actual result:

```
Name    City    Confirm
Vanessa Prague  OK
David   Prague  OK
Martin  Prague  Waiting
Frank   Prague  OK
Joseph  Prague  Waiting
```

I need:

```
Name    City    Confirm
Vanessa Prague  OK
David   Prague  OK
Frank   Prague  OK
```

Comment: Have you ever considered using a database to filter through tabular data?

Comment: Ofcourse, but I'm an amateur. This solution is sufficient for my little project, maybe later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, here is solution:
[PHP 5.2: Filter array with multiple arguments performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341563/php-5-2-filter-array-with-multiple-arguments-performance)

```
$arrayToCompare = array('type'=>'fruits','has_name'=>'OK', 'has_color'=>'Prague');

$new = array_filter(
                $data1,
                function ($arr) use ($arrayToCompare) { // PHP 5.3 is required here!!
                    return ($arr[2] == $arrayToCompare['has_name']
                        AND $arr[1] == $arrayToCompare['has_color']);
                }
            );
```